# jquery .closest().find().first().text() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Why the following JS not working on the HTML code?

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="uncle">Text to log</div>
  <div class="general-random-album-images">
    <a href="#" class="base-selector">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
$("a.base-selector").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('.grand-parent').find('.uncle').first().text());
});
```

I dont get the "Text to log" text in log.

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/MUny6/

Comment: Looks fine to me, are you sure the handler is executing at all?

Comment: @RUJordan that wouldn't be the right DOM tree traversal. http://jsfiddle.net/MUny6/1/

Comment: As Claudio has demonstarted, the code (when properly run) works just fine.  If it isn't working for you, then you need to make sure that it is executing and that you don't have any errors in your page or that you aren't trying to install the event handler before the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you wrap your code incorrectly since there is no other reason. Use either:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ // So we wait everything is loaded
    $("a.base-selector").click(function(){
      console.log($(this).closest('.grand-parent').find('.uncle').first().text());
    });
  });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
  $("body").on("click", "a.base-selector" function(){ // We filter
     console.log($(this).closest('.grand-parent').find('.uncle').first().text());
   });
</script>
```

Because you must wait everything is loaded.

Comment: Certainly no reason to wait for `$(window).load()`,  perhaps `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I think you should state that this is a wild guess at what might be wrong since you really have no evidence if `$(document).ready()` is needed or not.  It depends entirely upon the placement of the script.